# Why does this conversion give an error?

Tags: java, string, parsing, exception, int

I have this code in eclipse:

```
        String A = String.valueOf(a);
        String B = String.valueOf(b);
        String C = String.valueOf(c);
        String D = String.valueOf(d);
        String E = String.valueOf(e);
        String F = String.valueOf(f);
        String G = String.valueOf(g);
        String H = String.valueOf(h);
        String I = String.valueOf(i);
        String J = String.valueOf(j);
        String K = String.valueOf(k);

        String rawpassword = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K;
        int password = Integer.parseInt(rawpassword);
        System.out.println(password);
```

And it gives me this error

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.jakibah.codegenerator.Main.Generate(Main.java:65)
    at com.jakibah.codegenerator.Main.run(Main.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But I do not understand why.
can someone help me?

Comment: show us a,b,c...k and rawPassword

Comment: a = r.nextInt(10);
  b = r.nextInt(10);
  c = r.nextInt(10);
  d = r.nextInt(10);
  e = r.nextInt(10); 
  f = r.nextInt(10);
  g = r.nextInt(10);
  h = r.nextInt(10);
  i = r.nextInt(10);
  j = r.nextInt(10);
  k = r.nextInt(10); rawpassword is codestring sorry this was a older version of my class.

Comment: Your `rawpassword`String obviously does not contain a valid number.

Comment: use a loop please, you will save lines of code and gain in clarity and readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseInt(String s)` method throws a `NumberFormatException` if the argument is not a parseable `Integer`.

Make sure the `String` you pass to the method is a `Number` and is between `-2^31` and `2^31 - 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
    String A = String.valueOf(10);
    String B = String.valueOf(10);
    String C = String.valueOf(10);
    String D = String.valueOf(10);
    String E = String.valueOf(10);
    String F = String.valueOf(10);
    String G = String.valueOf(10);
    String H = String.valueOf(10);
    String I = String.valueOf(10);
    String J = String.valueOf(10);
    String K = String.valueOf(10);


    String codestring = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K;
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(codestring);
    System.out.println(bigInteger.max(bigInteger));
```

Answer (score 0):

Number Format exception arise when you trying to convert a string type into a integer but that does not fit as a integer.
From your code I am not able to understand what value is a,b,c,d,..
From my experience I have uploaded two image to show you may be this kind of error you done

[image]

here number format exception arise as codestring is 10.320 and it is a string type so when compiler try to convert it as a string it unable to convert it due to .

[image]

But in this scenario codestring is 1020 , so easily it convert to a int.